# changing the message with hooks

Tags: c++, hook, setwindowshookex

i want to learn a bit about how to use hooks so im trying to make a program that will change the input of 'A' to 'B',
i'm trying to use the WH_KEYBOARD hook and according to msdn:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
the WParam is "The virtual-key code of the key that generated the keystroke message.", so i tried to change it and use callNextHook.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(
  _In_  int code,
  _In_  WPARAM wParam,
  _In_  LPARAM lParam
)
{
if (wParam == 65)
wParam++;

CallNextHookEx(NULL, ncode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

i have tried to do something like that, and even without the "if" the changing of wParam doesn't affects the result.

what did i do wrong here? how can i make it to work?

thank you

Comment: Sorry to state the obvious but did you check the return value from `SetWindowsHookEx()` to make sure the hook actually installed properly?

Comment: yes i did and its installed properly, i also tried to return 1 to disable all keys and it works too

Comment: OK, what is the value of wParam when the hook is entered?

Comment: the wParam is changing according to what i do but the output still doesnt change.

Comment: is there any other way to do it?